# What is the name of this card game

Tags: identify-this-game

I played this game when I was younger but I cant remember its name, its a 2 player game,  3 cards in your hand, and then deal 2 cards face up in front of each person. You then have to each add a card from your hand to the face up card, with the aim being to have the highest combined numerical value (jack = 11, queen = 12, king 13 and ace 14). If you win, the face up cards on the table are discarded and you get a point (if there is a tie, then you both add another card from your hand and a third time if it is still a tie. if its a tie after the 3 hand cards then nobody gets a point). The unused cards in hands are added back to the draw deck and shuffled, the face up cards are discarded.You continue until there are not enough cards left in the draw deck to complete everyone's hands.

I'm trying to introduce it to friends , but I cant keep calling it "A card game I really like" does anyone know what its called?

Comment: information that might help people,  what do you mean by the 'highest value'. Is that sum of the card ranks, is it something similar to Three Card Poker?   Is claiming cards some sort of trick taking?  Is the game just 5 rounds long as your going through 10 cards a round?

Comment: Sounds a lot like [War](https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/war/)

Comment: The rules as given are pretty uninspiring. If the goal is to have the highest sum (of your given face-up card plus the one you play from your hand), then wouldn't you just play the highest card in your hand every time? Why would you ever play either of the lower ones? Expanding or correcting your explanation of the rules might help someone answer the question; right now you're describing a game that isn't _worthy_ of a name. ;P